# HtmlPage.Document.QueryString param value differs from DocumentUri.OriginalString value

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have a strange problem with request param value. Silverlight application is opened inside aspx page. Problem appears when my queryString contains equals sign. 
I inspected values in silverlight application and found out that value from uri differs from value retrieved as queryString parameter:

HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.OriginalString:

```
"http://localhost:8081/SilverlightContainer.aspx?sys_ObjectId=2&sys_Param1={\"p1\":\"Narud\\u017Ebenica =\"}"
```

HtmlPage.Document.QueryString["sys_Param1"]:

```
"{\"p1\":\"Narud\\u017Ebenica "
```

If `sys_Param1` doesn't contain equals sign everything works as expected.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your problem here? It seems you have a solution/workaround already.

Comment: What are you thinking of? Parsing DocumentUri.OriginalString? I don't want to do that. I would like to understand why is this happening and fix it properly.

Comment: I think you have to encode the '=' in a way or another. It seems the QueryString is constructed using something similar to `String.Split('=')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing problematic part of url and reading javascript variable from silverlight instead of passing it in querystring. 
Another way is using javascript encodeURIComponent but I decided to use variable approach.

I still don't know what causes this problem since my url look correct.